# How to hide current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a connection with my DB and my DB sends me some integer value like "1","2" or something like that.For example if my DB send me "3" I display the third page,it's working but my problem is when it displays the third page it's not hide my current page.I think my code is wrong in somewhere.Please help me

```
<script>
            function show(shown, hidden) {
                console.log(shown,hidden)
                $("#"+shown).show();
                $("#"+hidden).hide();
            }

            $(".content-form").submit(function(){
                var intRowCount = $(this).data('introwcount');
                var exec = 'show("Page"+data.result,"Page' + intRowCount + '")';
                ajaxSubmit("/post.php", $(this).serialize(), "", exec,"json");
                return false;
            })


            function ajaxSubmit(urlx, datax, loadingAppendToDiv, resultEval, dataTypex, completeEval) {
                 if (typeof dataTypex == "undefined") {
                    dataTypex = "html";
                }

                request = $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: urlx,
                    dataType: dataTypex,

                    data: datax,
                    async: true,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $(".modalOverlay").show();
                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        //$("div#loader2").remove();
                        loadingAppendToDiv !== "" ? $(loadingAppendToDiv).html(data) : "";
                        if (typeof resultEval !== "undefined") {
                            eval(resultEval);
                        } else {
                            //do nothing.
                        }

                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('An error occurred. Data does not retrieve.');
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        if (typeof completeEval !== "undefined") {
                            eval(completeEval);
                        } else {
                            //do nothing.
                        }
                        $(".modalOverlay").hide();
                    }

                });

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `eval` is bad mmmkay - just pass a callback anonymous function

Comment: Someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your helping my code working fine now.The problem is occured because of the cache. When I clear cache and cookies on Google Chrome it fixed.

Comment: my orginal code is running I just clear cache and cookies on Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter passed into the show() method is a bit wrong:

```
"Page' + intRowCount + '"
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
'Page' + intRowCount
```

Edit: wait wait you pass in a string of code to ajaxSubmit? What happens inside it?

If ajaxSubmit can use a callback, try this:

```
var exec = function(data) {
    show('Page' + data.result, 'Page' + intRowCount);
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not fixing my problem :(

Comment: in your solution it's not change the page anymore

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html is:

```
<div id='Page1'>..</div>
<div id='Page2'>..</div>
<div id='Page3'>..</div>
```

add a class to each of these div (use a sensible name, mypage just an example)

```
<div id='Page1' class='mypage'>..</div>
<div id='Page2' class='mypage'>..</div>
<div id='Page3' class='mypage'>..</div>
```

pass the page number you want to show and hide *all the others*, ie:

```
function showmypage(pageselector) {
    $(".mypage").hide();
    $(pageselector).show();
}
```

then change your 'exec' to:

```
var exec = 'showmypage("#Page"+data.result)';
```

---

It would be remiss of my not to recommend you remove the `eval`, so instead of:

```
var exec = "..."
```

use a function:

```
var onsuccess = function() { showmypage("#Page"+data.result); };
function ajaxSubmit(..., onsuccess, ...)
{
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        onsuccess();
    }
}
```

Comment: i added class ='mypage' all of my page div id's but could you please rewrite the final version of my function ?Because it's not fixing :/ i think i wrote something wrong

Comment: Could you please helping me ?